# How to install and run gaia astronomical software from starlink-hikianalia

Tags: macos, astronomy, gaia

I am trying to install gaia, image software for astronomy. I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and have xcode tools 3.2.6 with developer tools installed. I also believe I have the correct gfortran compiler necessary.

How do I install gaia now? What are the commands I need to run. When I download it, it unzips and there are just a bunch of folders.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: I found that I need to source the path in .bashrc, then gaia command will be recognized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Steps for installing Starlink Gaia

1. Download the latest Starlink distribution (Hikianalia, as of this writing):

   http://starlink.jach.hawaii.edu/starlink/HikianaliaDownload
2. Uncompress the .tar.gz. A new `star` directory will be created. You can move it some other place (for instance, `/Users/Shared/star`, or `/star`)

   1. As the installer is 0.7GB, you might want to delete it after installation has been successful.
3. Depending on your default shell:

   1. For C (`csh`, `tcsh`) shells:

      1. Create a `STARLINK_DIR` environment variable pointing to where the `star` directory is to be left (i.e., `/Users/Shared/star`):

         ```
         setenv STARLINK_DIR /Users/Shared/star
         ```
      2. Source the chsrc files

         ```
         source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/login
         source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/cshrc
         ```
      3. You can combine the steps above creating an alias called `start_starlink` to add to your .cshrc file, so that you only start the Starlink libraries when needed:

         ```
         alias start_starlink 'setenv STARLINK_DIR /Users/Shared/star; source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/login; source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/cshrc'
         ```
   2. For Bourne (`sh`, `bash`, `zsh`) shells:

      1. Create a `STARLINK_DIR` environment variable pointing to where the `star` directory is to be left (i.e., `/Users/Shared/star`):

         ```
         export STARLINK_DIR=/Users/Shared/star
         ```
      2. Source the chsrc files

         ```
         . $STARLINK_DIR/etc/profile
         ```
      3. You can combine the steps above creating an alias called `start_starlink` to add to your .cshrc file, so that you only start the Starlink libraries when needed:

         ```
         alias start_starlink='export STARLINK_DIR=/Users/Shared/star; . $STARLINK_DIR/etc/profile'
         ```

So, after typing `start_starlink`, you can just type `gaia` to launch Starlink Gaia.

## Fixing a missing `gfortran`

In x86_64 systems, if launching gaia fails with the message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/jdsant/Downloads/star/bin/gaia/gaia_wish
Reason: image not found
```

you need to make sure that you have gfortran libraries installed, and that they are were gaia expects them.

You can try to use `locate libgfortran.3.dylib`, and copy it to `/usr/local/lib` , or make a symlink to it. See, for instance, http://starlink.jach.hawaii.edu/starlink/HikianaliaDownload#SnowLeopard64-bitdistribution

Answer (score 0):

I had this

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/jdsant/Downloads/star/bin/gaia/gaia_wish
Reason: image not found
```

problem and was becoming very frustrated until I figured out that per the instructions on the GFortran website, that you must unzip the gcc file in the terminal, not using your browser. So, after downloading gcc-5.0-bin.tar.gz, I executed:

```
$ gunzip gcc-5.0-bin.tar.gz 
$ sudo tar -xvf gcc-5.0-bin.tar -C /
```

this unpacked the file, but then received a very long error stating "Application initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" and "gaia was not properly installed". I then executed:

```
$ startx
```

which started X11, and then opened xterm. I then restated in xterm:

```
$ export STARLINK_DIR=/Users/kristen/Downloads/star-2014A
$ source $STARLINK_DIR/etc/profile
$ gaia &
```

and another GUI for GAIA Starlink popped up and it all worked